# How to model a line reactor?

Tags: power, system

I have a project to model a transmission line with a reactor. I have searched about it but everywhere it basically says it is an inductor and mostly its application is given to protect the vfds and electrical drives. I have simulated the basic circuit for a line reactor with a Three Phase source, reactor(for which I used inductors), a fault in the line and three phase load, but it isn't sufficient. So please give your suggestions on how to proceed in this project of power system. I have to simulate it with a transmission line model and not with VFDs and drives. Also I want to know which hardware model can I make for this project.

Comment: What are your needs? An LRC-model should get you very close to the real thing in most fault cases.

Comment: A line reactor is an inductor, common mode choke. It has one core and 3 windings. It is used for VFDs - 1% to 3% voltage drop. Who could know what reactor you are calculating and for what purpose. generaly there are no reactors on the mains line (but I can be wrong on that).

Comment: @MarkoBuršič We absolutely put reactors in series with HV power lines. We do it to reduce the maximum short-circuit fault current. That is, to reduce the damage done during a short-circuit fault. Try searching "11kV Air Core Reactor" for some examples made by Alsom Grid, Trench, ABB, and others.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: How is this not sufficient? A reactor is literally an inductance, the only increase in model details from a network perspective would be to simulate saturation if you have a ferrite core base reactor.

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally need to model three-phase power systems with series reactors.

A simple lumped inductance and resistance model works well enough for steady-state conditions, i.e. short-circuit fault studies and load-flow studies.

Comment: Forget about my last comment, the question wasn't clear because of the text disposition.

Comment: To model an reactor, a lump inductance is actually more than fine for both steady-state and transient conditions. If OP is even simulating an air based reactor, saturation effect can be neglected.